# Supabase - cannot remove file from storage objects even directly after creating them

Tags: python, supabase

```
from supabase import create_client, Client
supabase: Client = create_client(url, key)
bucket_name: str = "manabi/objects"
data = supabase.storage.from_(bucket_name).upload("test_data.parquet", df)
data = supabase.storage.from_(bucket_name).remove("test_data.parquet")
```

Line 4 of this code runs fine, but line 5 tells me:
`StorageException: {'statusCode': 400, 'error': 'Not found', 'message': 'The resource was not found'}`

I have set up policies providing ALL access to all users as recommended by other users.

I'm fairly confident that for some reason, SELECT access isn't properly set up, because I also can't list the files in the folder, but I have no idea why it would allow me to upload and download but not select.

Comment: Can you share the policy you have set for your `storage.objects` table?